# Chrome Extension - Storage Set Specific Key In Object Without Override The Rest Of The Object?

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-extension

I have this obejct in storage

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
        user: {
            extensionMode: "filter",
            list: ["42", "42", "42"]
        }
    }, () => { });
```

Now, in a different place, I want to change the *extensionMode*:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({user: { extensionMode: wantedMode }}, () => { });
```

That's overwriting *user.list* .
How can I change just *extensionMode* without overwriting the rest of *user*?

Comment: There's no way to change just one property so you'll have to read/write the entire value. You can promisify the API and use the modern async/await syntax.

Answer (score 1):

My best answer so fat is this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("user", (res) => {
    let updatedUser = res.user;
    updatedUser.extensionMode = wantedMode;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ user: updatedUser }, () => {
        // Code
    });
});
```

It works! Just a bit messy and makes the callback hell worse :
Any other ideas?